# Java BufferedWriter encoding to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, bufferedwriter

I have a problem in writing an HTML String into a file as the characters appears as follows after writing :

```
Ø¹Ù…Ø§Ø¯Ø© Ø§Ù„ØªØ¹Ù„ÙŠÙ… Ø¹Ù† Ø¨Ø¹Ø
```

although i incode the stream to `UTF-8` as follows:

```
                Map<String,Object> param = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                param.put("traineeTPeriodCertificate", traineeTPeriodCertificate);
                String content = getTemplate("PublishGrade.html",param);
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try
                {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter
                    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:\\TraineesCertificates\\"+fileName),"UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(content);

                }
                catch ( IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

the String as i said is in HTML format:

```
<html dir="rtl" encoding="utf-8">
<body align="center">

    </body>
</html>
```

and `getTemplate` is as follows:

```
public String getTemplate(String templateName,
     Object dataModel) throws IOException,
    TemplateException {
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
Template freemarkerTemplate = null;
synchronized (templates) {
    freemarkerTemplate = templates.get(templateName);
    freemarkerTemplate = null;
    if (freemarkerTemplate == null) {
        freemarkerTemplate = cfg.getTemplate(templateName);
        templates.put(templateName, freemarkerTemplate);
    }
}
freemarkerTemplate.process(dataModel, stringWriter);
return stringWriter.toString();
```

}

Comment: Where is `content` from? Are you reading it as utf-8 also?

Comment: "In the file", well it *looks* like UTF8 encoded text to me. Does it appear correct in your browser?

Comment: no it appears in the browser as i state above

Comment: @Java Player Post where is `content` from, or we will be unable to help you...

Comment: Do these characters appear like that in your file editor or the html rendered to your web browser?

Comment: to the html rendered to your web browser

Comment: What do you see if you open your html file with a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting default encoding to freemarkerTemplate:
`freemarkerTemplate.setEncoding("UTF-8");`

Other thing is that i can't understand what is this:

```
freemarkerTemplate = templates.get(templateName);
freemarkerTemplate = null;
if (freemarkerTemplate == null) {
```

Comment: i tried to set the encoding of the template to UTF-8 but still not working!!